# How does the c++ compiler handle types declared inside conditionals?

Tags: c++, gcc, types, compilation

For example:

```
if ((rand() % 100) < 50)
    string value = "123";
else
    int value = 123;
```

Does the compiler know that value can have two possible types? How is this represented internally?

Comment: It doesn't. Anything that evaluates to zero is false, everything else is true.

Comment: juanchopanza, what about conditionals that must be evaluated at runtime?

Comment: They get evaluates, and if they are anything other than 0 they are true.

Comment: Google `programming scope`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not declare one variable with a type that is determined at runtime (or magically having two types), but in fact two independent variables, each of which has its own, static type and a lifetime that is restricted to its scope.

Each `value` is only alive within its own scope, which becomes clearer if you add the braces

```
if ((rand() % 100) < 50) {
    string value = "123";
    // 'value' refers to the string
}
else {
    int value = 123;
    // 'value' refers to the integer
}
// neither 'value' is alive here
```

The compiler does not care about variable names, they serve for the human programmer's information only. There is no name conflict here and the variables could as well be named differently.

Answer (score 4):

As far as the compiler is concerned this is no different to:

```
if ((rand() % 100) < 50)
    string aaa = "123";
else
    int bbb = 123;
```

i.e. the fact you use the same name in two different scopes is completely irrelevant.

If the condition is true the compiler creates a `string` on the stack, otherwise it creates an `int` on the stack. The names you give those objects in your source code are irrelevant.

There are two different objects, with two different types, but which one gets created at runtime depends on the condition.

On entry to the function the compiler will reserve enough stack space for the larger of `string` and `int`, then at runtime initialize either a string or an int at that memory location, and if `sizeof(string) != sizeof(int)` then some of the reserved stack space will be unused on some executions.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler will consider 2 distinct scopes for the 2 branches. If you will try to use "**value**" outside of the branch, without declaring it previously it will throw an error. (undefined identifier)

Your construct has no sense if you don't make something with "**value**" on each branch.

As an example, if you do something like this:

```
int value = 10;
value = 5;

if ((rand() % 100) < 50)
    string value = "123"
else
    int value = 123

printf("%d\n", value);
```

it will type 5.